How do i upload images to Cloudinary with Next.js?
I have a problem with my code. I am building an e-commerce website where I sell products. I have installed Cloudinary because I heard it is a good way to store images, and I want to showcase it to companies in my portfolio. I have created the Cloudinary config file, but I don't understand how to upload images to Cloudinary and then save the URL to my MongoDB database. I was thinking of using Insomnia for testing purposes so I can upload an image there and send a POST request. How can I continue with this code so that it works for posting in Insomnia and creating a product in MongoDB with the updated image URL? Here is my Cloudinary config code and an upload function:
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";

const connectCloudinary = async () => {
  cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
  });
};

export const uploadImage = async (filePath: string) => {
  try {
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(filePath, {
      folder: "images",
    });

    return result.secure_url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image to Cloudinary:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to upload image.");
  }
};

connectCloudinary();


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



//Here is my product.ts for addition of new products and handling images: 

import connectDB from "@/libs/db/mongodb";
import productModel from "@/models/productModel";
import { uploadImage } from "../cloud/cloudinary";

export const createProduct = async (
  name: string,
  description: string,
  price: Number,
  images: string[],
  category: string,
  subCategory: string,
  sizes: string[],
  soldout: boolean
) => {
  await connectDB();

  const uploadedImages = await Promise.all(images.map(async (image) => await uploadImage(image)));

 
  const newProduct = new productModel({
    name,
    description,
    price,
    images: uploadedImages,
    category,
    subCategory,
    sizes,
    soldout,
  });
  return newProduct.save();
};







--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// And in my api folder I have a file called route.ts to handle post requests:

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { createProduct } from '@/libs/services/product'; 
import productModel from '@/models/productModel';
import connectDB from '@/libs/db/mongodb';

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { name, description, price, image, category, subCategory, sizes, soldout }  = await req.json();

 

  try {
    const product = await createProduct(name, description, price, image, category, subCategory, sizes, soldout);

    
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Product created successfully', product }, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error creating product', error }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

export async function GET() {
    await connectDB();
    try {
        const products = await productModel.find({});
        return NextResponse.json(products, { status:200 });
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({message: 'Error fetching products'}, {status: 500});
    }
}


I tried using multipart/form data to choose an image but that didnt work because i needed either multer or formidable but didnt understand how to apply it to my code. Since nextjs has a built-in api routing, I use my mapstructure as api routes when i send post requests in my insomnia.

Map structure of the project

what is the error message in try/catch block

Also, you may check out this NextJS sample project showing the use of Cloudinary SDK: https://github.com/colbyfayock/next-cloudinary
